# Python - Using while loops in functions

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to create a function that uses a while loop to count up from one to a number given by a user. The code executes as I intend it to but returns None at the end. How do I get rid of the None? Here's the code.

```
def printFunction(n):
    i = 1
    while i <= n:
        print(i)
        i+=1


print (printFunction(int(input())))
```

Comment: Replace `print (printFunction(int(input()))` with `printFunction(int(input())` - don't print the return value if there's nothing being returned.

Comment: If you don’t want to see None, don’t print the return value of a function that doesn’t return anything?

Comment: Thnx for the edit. Can you show me how you did that?

Comment: You highlight your code and hit ctrl+k.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code to prevent none, tough its just the last line changed

```
def printFunction(n):
i = 1
while i <= n:
    print(i)
    i+=1
printFunction(int(input()))
```

In the last line you were using 
 `print(printFunction(int(input())))` which was getting you None after printing the results.

Instead just use `printFunction(int(input()))`. This will not print None. You can also use a message to ask user like `printFunction(int(input("Enter a number")))`. Since there is noting getting returned you no need to use `print`.

Comment: `printFunction` is the name of the function. `Function` is not defined.

Comment: ...did you read the question?